# Proof of the finite number of Bravais lattices?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, integer-lattices

I've been taught that there are a finite number of Bravais lattices in 1, 2 and 3 dimensions. I am wondering if there is a proof of this fact. Maybe this is obvious and I am only missing certain key assumptions that are made in setting the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In fact, there are only finitely many Bravais lattices in *every* dimension $n\ge 1$.
The numbers are $1$, $4$, $14$, $64$ in dimensions $1,2,3,4$. The proof follows from a famous theorem of Jordan,

**Theorem(Jordan):** The group $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ has only finitely many conjugacy classes of finite subgroups.

Bravais lattices correspond here to conjugacy classes of certain finite subgroups, the so called Bravais subgroups. The group $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ arises here as the automorphism group of the full lattice $\mathbb{Z}^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. 
More generally there are *only finitely many* crystallographic groups in each dimension $n\ge 1$. This was asked by Hilbert in his list of famous problems of $1900$ (problem $17$), and was answered by Bieberbach $10$ years later. 
The proof is easier, of course, if we assume $n\le 3$. Here it suffices just to classify all conjugacy classes of finite subgroups of $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ for $n=1,2,3$. The lists can be found in papers of Schulz and Plesken on the classification of crystallographic groups.

Comment: I was hoping to ask you a relatively simple question - what is the formal mathematical definition of a Bravais Lattice?

Comment: @EricNaslund Are you satisfied with the definition from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bravais_lattice)?

Comment: I was expecting to find a definition of the form "A Bravais lattice is a lattice invariant under symmetry group X", but I could not find this anywhere, and I am not sure it is right anymore?